# FindItems() and BindToItems() give inconsistent results for EmailMessage.Sender.Address

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, managed-ews

After quite a lot of debugging, I've refined a complicated Managed EWS problem down to the following two simple-ish test cases.  The first one works, the second one fails:

```
var view = new ItemView(100) { PropertySet = new PropertySet { EmailMessageSchema.Id } };
var findResults = ews.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view)
var bindResults = ews.BindToItems(findResults.Select(r => r.Id), new PropertySet { EmailMessageSchema.Sender });

// Sanity check
Assert.AreEqual(1, bindResults.Count());

// The results I care about
Assert.AreEqual("David Seiler", bindResults[0].Sender.Name);
Assert.AreEqual("david.seiler@yahoo.com", bindResults[0].Sender.Address);
```

One might try to cut out the `BindToItems()` call, and use `FindItems()` directly:

```
var view = new ItemView(100) { PropertySet = new PropertySet { EmailMessageSchema.Sender } };
var findResults = ews.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view)

// This part still works fine
Assert.AreEqual(1, findResults.Count());

// So does this
Assert.AreEqual("David Seiler", findResults[0].Sender.Name);

// ...but this fails!  Sender.Address is null
Assert.AreEqual("david.seiler@yahoo.com", findResults[0].Sender.Address);
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?  It really seems, from the documentation, as though this should work.  Not all properties can be read through `FindItems()`, it's true, but those properties usually throw when I try to access them, and anyway there's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508824%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) of those properties on MSDN and `Sender` isn't on it.  What's going on?

Comment: I noticed a similar issue with Contacts and e-mail addresses.  I thought it might have something to do with the global address book since I would get a strange format when the contact was retrieved with 'FindItems'.  The answer below helped me out (I don't like the extra call, but in my case it's manageable).  service.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't know why, but in the second option, it only load basic information of the sender like the name, but not the Address.

If you want to load all the sender properties but do not want to bind the full message you can add the following line before the first assert

```
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Sender));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is there a current, accurate list someplace of the properties which are and are not loaded by FindItems()?  I linked to one in my question, but it's a few years old and doesn't include this case.  Better still: do you know of a way to get all the properties I want *without* the second network roundtrip?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I was having the same issue and couldn't find a good documentation source. Everything I know was learned the hard way